# Форматированный ввод бинарного файла

Tags: c++, файлы

Открываю файл в бинарном режиме, но при этом форматированный ввод с помощью `>>` [компилируется](https://godbolt.org/z/6M6Mvd). Какое поведение ожидать от такого кода с т.з. стандарта?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream in{"test.bin", std::ios_base::binary};

    int x;
    in >> x;

    std::cout << x;
}
```

Comment: Такого и ожидать - пока там реальные цифры - читает, нет - fail...

Comment: Открытие файла в бинарном режиме не запрещает форматированный ввод. Оно влияет на некоторые возможности транслирования бинарного представления данных в получаемое. Например на windows может отключаться преобразование `\r\n` <-> `\n` и т.п. Однако в приведенном примере отсутствует флаг открытия на чтение и проверки, открылся файл или нет и прочиталось что-то или нет. К сожалению, это все действительно спокойно компилируется.

Comment: @user7860670 флаг и проверка необязательны же для чтения

Comment: Такого и ожидать - пока там реальные цифры - читает, нет - fail...

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/549519)